# `perl -pe` vs `sed`, performance-wise

Tags: macos, perl, sed

On OSX, the system `sed` seems, at times, a bit limited regarding regular expressions and some escape characters — so much, that I end up using `perl -pe` a fair bit of the time, and now I’m wondering if I should care about using `sed` at all.

I usually need this when piping a lot of commands in a row, usually calling `sed` and `perl` multiple times during its execution, and I’d like to know if I should use `sed` when it does the job, using `perl` only when it is necessary. I’m interested in this from a performance point of view (having multiple commands of this kind in a script can make a difference in the end), but if there are any other considerations you deem worthy of mentioning, they’re welcome, naturally.

Comment: You should probably move this to another StackExchange site, like Unix or SuperUser.

Comment: Actually, he should run a benchmark.

Comment: If you are piping a lot of commands in a row, you are most likey not using either sed or perl correctly. Having achieved the desired result review the procedures used and try and reduce the number of processes by `moving` them into either  sed or perl. Always try to reduce the input first as this will mean future processes will have less work to do. HTH

Comment: @ikegami Those scripts are run on a variety of computers with different specs. Having never run any kind of benchmarks myself, I’d rather trust someone with some experience on this.

Comment: @potong I’m not just piping `sed` and `perl` repeatedly, they have other commands in the middle, that are interwoven.

Comment: Why do you think we have knowledge of your computers of varied and unspecified specs?

Comment: Assuming all computers would be equal in performance, and you're more concerned with performance differences between perl and sed, versus enhanced capabilities with perl, use what you're most comfortable with!

Comment: @ikegami I don’t, I’m asking in general. Certain tools are always slower than others, when run on the same computer.

Comment: Then what's stopping you from benchmarking it?

Comment: Again, “having never run any kind of benchmarks myself, I’d rather trust someone with some experience on this”. This information is not mission critical, and I can’t afford (right now) the time to go into how do it, prepare, run, and interpret the results. For this particular question, I’m interested in a quick answer, not a method.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Perl is probably a bit slower than `sed` (but not by much — it is a very fast scripting language); however, if Perl does what you need and `sed` doesn't, use Perl.

Note that Perl is (still) distributed with the programs `s2p` and `a2p` which convert `sed` and `awk` scripts respectively into Perl.  So you can devise your script in `sed` and then automatically translate to Perl (and adapt to exploit enhanced Perl regular expressions, etc).